# ¿Cómo realizo una copia del “contenido” de un arreglo de caracteres a otro arreglo sin utilizar la dirección original del arreglo?

Tags: c, string, punteros

Necesito enviar una copia del contenido de la cadena almacenada en **nuevo->urlCompleto** a convertirURL(char*) que recibe en puntero de tipo **char*** dado que el parámetro será modificado en la función por lo que no puedo utilizar la dirección original.
Este es el código que estaba probando pero igual toma como entrada la dirección original.

```
char* cadena = (char*)malloc(sizeof(nuevo->urlCompleto));
strcpy(cadena, nuevo->urlCompleto);
strcpy(nuevo->codigo, convertirURL(cadena));
```

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer una copia de un libro sin abrir el libro original? Obviamente no, pues aquí es lo mismo, para poder copiar un array tienes que tener acceso a los datos originales.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir "pero igual toma como entrada la dirección original."? Veo que en el codigo `convertirUrl` recibe `cadena` que es una copia de `nuevo->urlCompleto` así que no tienen la misma dirección de memoria.

Comment: pero al imprimir el condenido de nuevo->urlCompleto despues de   strcpy(nuevo->codigo, convertirURL(cadena)); la cadena se encuentra sin contenido por lo que en algun punto si se usa la direccion original

Comment: Si el contenido de `nuevo->urlCompleto` cambia despues de `strcpy(nuevo->codigo, convertirURL(cadena));` significa que `codigo` y `urlCompleto` apuntan al mismo lugar

Comment: Bueno para empezar, estas haciendo mal la copia. `sizeof(nuevo->urlCompleto)` te va a dar el tamaño de un `char*`, no el tamaño de la cadena. Tiene que ser: `strlen(nuevo->urlCompleto)+1`. Aparte de eso no te puedo ayudar, ya que no puedo reproducir el error. Tienes que traer un [ejemplo minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) @fyxov

Comment: De hecho, la copia a `nuevo->codigo` tambien esta mal a excepcion que `convertirUrl` regrese `cadena`. Claro, no se puede saber si nos faltan detalles

Comment: Como te ha comentado @Pablochaches hace falta un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Tiene pinta que no estás gestionando correctamente la memoria, pero es imposible darte más detalles si no nos proporcionas un ejemplo real